# Use Xerces library in a C++ project on eclipse

Tags: c++, xerces-c

I must use Xerces to read a XML file for my project. I'm coding on Eclipse. I have the file .so of Xerces library and I added it in properties of my project.

Now there is no problem to find the files .h of the library Xerces but it's impossible to use the namespace xercesc. Eclipse doesn't recognize this namespace and I don't know why.
If someone have the solution ?

Thank you:)

Comment: Inspect your xerces header files. Is the `XERCES_HAS_CPP_NAMESPACE` preprocessor macro defined to 1?

Comment: Yes the XERCES_HAS_CPP_NAMESPACE preprocessor macro is defined to 1